# How does 'such as' mean 'of the kind or degree that' and 'the kind of (person or thing) that?

Tags: syntax, prepositional-phrases

> [such as](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such-as?q=such+as) {prepositional phrase} = 2. Of a kind that; like
>    3. (archaic) Those who
>
> [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193400?rskey=S7S02U&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) 7.  a. With correlative *as* pron. (see [AS conj. 17](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307#eid38320125)), Middle English also *as that*, taking the place of Old English *swelce, swá*.
>   ***such as*** = Of the kind or degree that; the kind of (person or thing) that.

[This ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/180382/50720) helped explain definitions 2 and 3 by interjecting (ellipted?) words between **such as** (exemplified in this other [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/51643/8712)).

**My Problem:** 6 months after asking this question, whenever encountering the above definitions of **such as**, I still must suspend reading to perform the interjection above, which  betrays some mental defect in my understanding.
I wish to surmount and to be cured of this dependence on interjection.
So what have I missed or failed to understand? How can I naturalise the definitions above?

Answer (score 1):

You reason correctly, but there is an easier way.

Definition 3 makes "such as" equivalent to "those who". This needs to be followed by a verb:

Those who [do x]  [are/do/other verb].
e. g. "Those who live in glass houses should not throw stones."  "Such as live in glass houses should not throw stones."

So, if you see "such as" followed by a verb (and you rarely will, as this usage is archaic) it is definition 3.

If you see "such as" followed by a noun, it must be definition 1 or 2. And it should not be too difficult to gather from context whether it is 1 or 2. At least, you didn't ask about distinguishing def 1 from def 2.

Comment: Thank you. I admit that I didn't `ask about distinguishing def 1 from def 2` because I overlooked this; so would you please explain this as well?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment which is less readable?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but were you please able to read my comments above?

Comment: Now I don't even see a "def 1" in your question. I have entirely forgotten what I meant in regard to #1.  Sorry.